# What is the formula to solve a cubic equation?

Tags: cubics

I know that to solve $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

you have to use the formula $$x=  \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{(b^2-4ac)}}{2a}$$

What about more complex ones, like $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$? And what about representing it on a cordinate plane, $2D$ or $3D$?

Comment: See [General solution to the cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to solve polynomial equations up to degree 4 in terms of radicals. For example, to solve a cubic equation, have a look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients

There is no general algebraic formula to solve a polynomial equation that has degree 5 or higher in terms only of radicals.